# Out of 3 partitions on an external harddrive, 1 partition is not accessible

Tags: external-hard-drive

I had a Dell latitude D 620 to which I connect an external harddisk.
I made 3 partitions on the external hard disk and I compressed the third partition.

On connecting hard disk to that laptop I could access all 3 drives.

Now I don't have the laptop in my possession. If I connect the hard disk to any other laptop I can access only 2 partitions. The 3rd is not accessible.

This 3rd partition has around 100GB data in it still the 3rd partion size is seen as 0 on connecting it the to other laptops.

Please suggest me a method to extract data from the 3rd partition & make it accessible & operable.

Comment: what do you mean with compressed? Encrypted with bitlocker?

Answer (score 0):

Open computer management by rightclicking on my computer and selecting manage. 
Open storage -> disk management and you'll see the hard disk there. assign it a drive letter and you'll be good to go.
I'm assuming windows as you didn't specify your OS.